# $a_0=0,a_{n+1}^3=a_n^2-8.$ How to prove the series $\sum |a_{n+1}-a_n|$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that there is a sequence defined as below
$$a_0=0,a_{n+1}^3=a_n^2-8$$
How to prove the series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|a_{n+1}-a_n|$ converges?

I know that $a_n$ converge to a fixed point, but the question is how to estimate how fast $a_n$ converges to the fixed point.

*From comment:* $a_n$ converges to the root of the equation $x^3−x^2+8=0$, which is approximately equal to $-1.716$,and $a_n$ converges alternating to it.

Comment: What have you tried?  What does $a_n$ converge to?  Does $a_n$ converge monotonically or alternating or some other pattern?

Comment: @Henry:$a_n$ converge to the root of the equation $x^3-x^2+8=0$,which is approximately equal to -1.716,and $a_n$ converge alternating to it.

Comment: If you could show ${|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|}<k{|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|}$ for some $k<1$ then you could prove convergence.  You might have to restrict yourself to cases such as $a_n\le 0$

Comment: @Henry: Thanks for your hint, I think I have already solved it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_n = -a_n$ and we observe:

1. $b_n \in [0, 2]$ for all $n\geq 0$. Indeed,

   - $b_0 = 0$ and hence the the claim is true for $n = 0$.
   - Assuming the claim for $n$, we have $b_{n+1} = \sqrt[3]{8 - b_n^2} \in [0, 2]$ because $\sqrt[3]{8 - 4} \geq 0$.

   Hence the bound follows from mathematical induction.
2. The intermediate step of the above proof actually reveals that

   $$b_n \in [c, 2] \tag{1} $$

   for all $n \geq 1$, where $c = \sqrt[3]{4} \approx 1.5874$.
3. Since $x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{8 - x^2}$ is decreasing in $x$ for $x \geq 0$, we know that
   $$x = \sqrt[3]{8 - x^2}$$
   has a unique zero in the range $[0, \sqrt{8}]$, which we denote by $\beta$. Although the value of $\beta$ mostly plays no role in solving OP's problem, one crucial observation is that $\beta \in [c, 2]$ where $c$ is defined as in Item 2. This is indeed obvious from Item 2.

   [image: Graph]

Using these observations, we investigate the difference between $b_n$ and $\beta$. For any $n \geq 0$,

\begin{align*}
\left| b_{n+1} - \beta \right|
&= \left| \frac{b_{n+1}^3 - \beta^3}{b_{n+1}^2 + b_{n+1}\beta + \beta^2} \right| \\
&= \left| \frac{(8 - b_n^2) - (8 - \beta^2)}{b_{n+1}^2 + b_{n+1}\beta + \beta^2} \right| \\
&= \frac{b_n + \beta}{b_{n+1}^2 + b_{n+1}\beta + \beta^2} \cdot \left| b_n - \beta \right| \\
&\leq \frac{4}{3c^2} \left| b_n - \beta \right|. \tag{by (1)}
\end{align*}

Repeatedly applying this bound, we get

\begin{align*}
\left| b_n - \beta \right|
\leq \rho^n \left| \beta \right|, \qquad \text{where } \rho = \frac{4}{3c^2}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Then by noting that $\rho^3 = \frac{64}{27 \cdot 16} = \frac{4}{27} < 1$, we have $\rho < 1$. Hence,

\begin{align*}|a_{n+1} - a_n|
&= |b_{n+1} - b_| \\
&\leq |b_{n+1} - \beta| + |b_n - \beta| \\
&\leq \rho^{n+1}|\beta| + \rho^{n}|\beta| \tag{by (2)}
\end{align*}

From $\sum_n \rho^n < \infty$, the desired conclusion follows.

Comment: You could also bound the increment the same way you bound the distance to the fixed point. Just replace $\beta$ with $b_n$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, You are right! Thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

$a_0=0$, $a_1=-2$, and the function
$$f:[-2,0]\to[-2,0],\quad x\mapsto\sqrt[3]{x^2-8}$$
satisfies
$$f'(x)=\frac{2x}{3\left|x^2-8\right|^{2/3}}\in[f'(-2),f'(0)]=[r,0],\quad r=-\frac{\sqrt[3]4}3\in(-1,0).$$
By the mean value theorem,
$$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=r_n(a_{n+1}-a_n),\quad r_n\in(r,0),$$
hence the series $\sum(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ is alternating, and absolutely convergent.